# Title search: ISS and UFO

Tags: story-identification

The story has a SETI expert sent to the ISS when a mysterious object appears near the ISS. She's Sally someone, the story is mainly set in Russia, an American named John Bales takes over the Russian astronaut base with NASA backing. A journo gets involved, Bales & his nasty mates threaten the journo.

Comment: Is this a book, a movie or a TV show?

Comment: And when did you see / read it?

Answer (score 6):

Likely it is, **Vessel** by Andrew J. Morgan

Below is a small excerpt from the story:

> 'My name is John Bales, and I have been sent by NASA to work closely with you all following the recent discovery of the unidentified vessel that we have code-named UV One. It has been decided in a joint negotiation between our two states that should the situation escalate to a point that our astronauts are in a state of immediate danger, our expertise and authority — NASA's expertise and authority — will take command. That time —'

See this sample for more details: http://kindleweb.s3.amazonaws.com/content/B00MAGGFCE/gz_sample.html